# Rails 4.2 overriding views. Is Deface really standalone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, deface

I'm trying to override view with Deface.

In manual creators called it standalone, so I guess that it's possible to use this gem without using spree... But I'm not sure anymore because nearly every tutorial/question/anything I found about Deface was related to spree.

However I tried. what I done was adding a line to Gemfile

> gem 'deface'

and running

> bundle install

which for sure installed deface gem.

Then I made route like this:

```
get 'test', to: 'test#show'
```

empty controller `app/controllers/test_controller.rb`

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def show

  end
end
```

and view like this `app/views/test/show.html/erb`

```
<h1 id="test">test first</h1>
```

then I go to `cd app` and make directory overrides `mkdir overrides` and created `app/overriders/test_uploader.rb` which contains:

```
Deface.Override.new(
  :virtual_path => 'test/show',
  :name => 'test uploader',
  :replace => 'h1#test',
  :text => '<h1 id="test">replaced, test passed</h1>'
)
```

But even if I reloaded server nothing happened.
Why? Had I missed something? Or maybe I really needs spree to use Deface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why your code sample not working but I did simple sample also for you and its works very well. You can download code project here https://github.com/nezirz/deface_gem

Also here is a screen shoot:[image]